# How to extract all URLs from a long string in a textbox and paste into another?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if it's possible to have 2 textareas in a page and using a regular expression copy all the URLs from a first textarea with a  really (I mean REALLY long) long string and insert in the second textarea?

I will also need to use the same idea to extract different string patterns from the same string, that's why I was wondering if it's possible to use a regular expression that I could change to match my other requirements.

Can anyone enlighten me on that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add ids to your text areas. After that it's just manipulation (using jQuery or not).

1. Parse your text area value, looking for the url patttern;
2. Save it to a variable;
3. Use this variable value to add to second text area value.

I'll try to create an example in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to clarify the idea.